# How to list players as available for transfer in 2011

Tags: fifa-11

I have one wally in the team I would like to sell before his contract runs out. How can I set him as 'available for transfer' or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Transfers and Sell Players, find the player, press 'A' (360) which brings up a context menu, select for sale and this will change his status to listed. It doesn't mean you will be able to sell him though, there seems to be strange bugs around not being able to get rid of players, even good ones .. despite things like their wages not being too high etc.

Good luck.